# how do you rotate an image at a 40degree angle from left to right?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying with jQuery or js to get an image rotate left to right constantly after upload (no button).

Comment: you need to add appropriate CSS to the appropriate (img?) element to do this - or add a class which has the required CSS of course

Comment: Just like @JaromandaX said, add a class .40-degrees-clockwise and apply it to your image upon loading, that should be the same as what you do with a button. (if needed, a CSS rotation looks like this `.40-degrees-clockwise{transform: rotate(40deg);}`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it will be helpful.

```js
const img = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]
img.addEventListener("load", function(){
  img.classList.remove('rotateRight');
  img.classList.add('rotateLeft');
});
```

```css
img{
heigth :200px;
width : 200px;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ;
}
.rotateRight{
transform: rotate(-40deg);
}
.rotateLeft{
transform: rotate(40deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
<img class ="rotateRight" src='https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords.jpg'/> 
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, I'll start with this code to try to make it rotate right as well and make sure the movement is constant!